# Сохранить текущую дату и время в Clickhouse

Tags: java, spring-boot, clickhouse

Пытаюсь сохранить текущую дату в `Clickhouse` и почему-то время, которое отображает консольный клиент, отличается от местного на два часа назад. То есть если я хочу залогировать событие, произошедшее в 13 часов дня, то в кликхаусе время будет 11 часов утра.

Реализация логгера такая:

```
@Component
public class ClickhouseLogger {

    private final static String query = "insert into notification_logs.email_logs(send_time, event_type, recipient, subject, content, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    public void log(String eventType, String recipient, String subject, String content, String status) {

        Connection connection = Clickhouse.Instance.getConnection();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            //ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(time), utc);
            ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(time));
            ps.setString(2, eventType);
            ps.setString(3, recipient);
            ps.setString(4, subject);
            ps.setString(5, content);
            ps.setString(6, status);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

В строчке `ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(time));` дата-время сохраняется со смещением на два часа назад. В строке `ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(time), utc);`, которую я закомментировал, и вовсе возникает исключение с сообщением об операции, которая неподдерживается, и что-то там про null.

Как правильно сохранять дату-время в `CH`? В документации на их сайте говорится о том, что дата сохраняется как 4-байтовое целое без знака (привет, проблема 2038 года) и в эту сторону разработчики не копали.

Comment: А в настройках кликХауса локальное время какое и какой часовой пояс? А также, у вас он показывает логи "на лету", т.е. в него напрямую передают или вычитывая откуда-то?

Comment: @Dred, я не настраивал кликхаус, а просто запустил его в докере. Логи пишу в КХ сразу же при возникновении события. Читаю данные из таблицы при помощи консольного клиента от яндекса.

Comment: Проверьте настройки самого КХ. Может он выводит по вашему часовому поясу,а не по тому, когда произошло событие. В инструкции об этом что-то написано. Мы только настраиваем его, поэтому более точно пока не могу сказать